# Why does my tkinter label suddenly disappear?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a chess AI. I need a chess set in order to play. I made the pieces (they can be dragged), board, clock, etc. Right now, I am trying to make the clock alternate when someone plays. During one of my tests to make the clock alternate, the clock for the ai suddenly disappeared. I checked if I forgot anything like did I add the grid method, put it in the root, saved, etc. I did all of them. I tried changing the numbers in row. It was originally 0. I tried 1 and it reappeared. But it was not in the place I wanted, so I changed the number again from 1 to 2 to see if it still works. But it disappeared. I put back one but it was still gone(I checked twice if I saved). Here's the code for the ai clock:

```
from root_frame import Root
from tkinter import Label

ai_turn = False

class AI: 
    def __init__(self):      
        self.the_screen = Root()       
        self.ai_label = Label(self.the_screen.root, text = "AI", font = "Helvetica 18 bold", width = 40)
        self.ai_clock = Label(self.the_screen.root, font = "Helvetica 18 bold")
    
    def set_timer(self):
        self.t = 600
        return self.t

    def countdown(self):
        global ai_turn

        if self.t > 0 and ai_turn == True:
            self.convert()
            self.t = self.t - 1
            self.ai_clock.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown())
            print("it's running dum dum")

        elif self.t == 0:
            self.ai_clock.config(text = "ai loose")
        
        elif ai_turn == False:
            print("it's not running dum dum")
            self.t = self.t

    def convert(self): 
        self.seconds = self.t % (24 * 3600) 
        self.seconds %= 3600
        self.minutes = self.t // 60
        self.seconds %= 60
        self.ai_clock.config(text = "%02d:%02d" % (self.minutes, self.seconds))

    def stop(self):
        global ai_turn
        ai_turn = False
        if ai_turn == False:
            print("ai stopped, value: {}".format(ai_turn))

    def go(self):
        global ai_turn
        ai_turn = True
        if ai_turn == True:
            print("ai active, value: {}".format(ai_turn))
```

And here is where I grid them:

```
class Screen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.AI = AI()
        self.Human = Human()
        self.AI.ai_clock.grid(row = 0, column = 9)
        self.Human.human_clock.grid(row = 7, column = 8)

        "Run functions to activate the clocks"
        self.AI.set_timer()
        self.AI.countdown()
        self.Human.set_timer()
        self.Human.countdown()
```

And finally, here is root_frame:

```
from tkinter import Tk

class Root:
    root = Tk()
```

(There's indent because it was in a method)Thanks!

Comment: It's where I store the root = Tk().

Comment: It is used in many place in my code so I decided to put it in a file. That's the only thing that it contains

Comment: That is in one of my test. When I added the go method, the clock didn't go, so I thought that it didn't change or something. So I made sure of it by making the if statement. And the self.t is a mistake, I'll erase it.

Comment: I added it. It only contais the root = Tk()

Comment: Why wouldn't it run?

Comment: And when I putted the ai_turn variable in init, the stop method didn't work anymore

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: I created an instance of AI. But I didn't show it here because there was a guy in another post that told me not to post to much code, just enough to understand

Comment: But I have a lot of code, if I post the ones that need to be able to work, the page will be very long

Comment: This is all the code that uses the ai class and their is a main.py file that runs the entire program but the ai label, time file isn't in main, it is used by other files that are in main

Comment: Building a MRE is part of your trouble shooting. By narrowing down the issue to something smaller you may discover on your own why it is not working. If not then you can post that MRE here. With the code the way it is now we cannot run it and therefor cannot test the problems. If you simply cannot reduce your code or dont know how to then post a link to a pastebin in your question and note that you are not sure how to reduce it to an MRE. I cannot say it wont be downvoted but someone may help you learn how to post with that code.

Comment: What is `Human()` doing?

Comment: I had another class called Human(). It is the same as ai, it has a label and a clock and methods to make the clock stop and go.But human works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `self.AI.countdown()` exactly once. In it, you only start the timer if `self.t>0` and `ai_turn == True`. However, `ai_turn` is `False`, so the timer never starts. If you set `ai_turn` to True at the start of the program the timer will work.

All you have to do to discover this is put a `print` statement right before your `if` statement to verify your assumptions about those variables. Also, if you give the label a distinct color you will see that it is on the screen but very small because by default it has no text in it.

In other words, the label appears just fine, and is updated properly as long as you have the logic in place to start the timer.